# how to send multiple fileds value through foreach loop?

Tags: php, html

How could I send multiple fields values through a foreach loop, by using the same `ID`?

Whats wrong with this HTML code?

```
<input type="text" size="3" name="new_quantity[<?php echo $product_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="totalcost[<?php echo $product_id; ?>]" value="<?php $total_cost; ?>"  />
```

Now the `PHP` code

```
foreach($_REQUEST['new_quantity'] as  $key => $quantity) {
    foreach($_REQUEST['totalcost'] as $key => $total) {
        $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE `categories`.`carts` SET `product_quantity` = '$quantity',                `product_totalcost` = '$total' WHERE `carts`.`product_id` ='$key' AND  cart_session='$sessionID'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop inside a loop will give you n*n times update query

But you actually need update query n times

so do it like this :

```
$pids     = array_keys($_REQUEST['new_quantity']); /// here you will get all product_ids

for($i=0; $i<count($_REQUEST['new_quantity']);$i++){
   echo $_REQUEST['new_quantity'][$pids[$i]]; // this quantity
   echo $_REQUEST['totalcost'][$pids[$i]]; // total cost
   echo $pids[$i]; // product id

   /// add your update query here all details you need in query are echoed above.
}
```

Comment: Edited the answe, please check it now

Answer (score -1):

try to do one thing make one array for **quantity** and one for **cost**

like

```
$qt=array();
foreach($_REQUEST['new_quantity'] as  $key => $quantity) {
$qt[].=$quantity;
}

$ct=array();
foreach($_REQUEST['totalcost'] as $key => $total) {
$ct[].=$total;
}
```

then fire the update query in for loop

Comment: all the values will appended in the array with successive indices

Comment: You don't need `.` for that `$qt[] =$quantity;` this will work